# PHP Script to download a webpage's source code and search for a specific string

Tags: php

I need help crafting a PHP code that accomplishes the following:

1. Access a website (www.example.com)
2. Download its source code into a string variable
3. Search this specific string for a specific content such as

   `<div class="news" title="news alert">Click to get news alert</div>`

Basically I need to search the source code for `title="news alert"`

Thank you all,

Comment: What do you want to return from the element that has `title="news alert"`?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$text = file_get_contents('http://example.com/path/to/file.html');
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->loadHTML($text);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('div') AS $div) {
    $class = $div->getAttribute('class');
    if(strpos($class, 'news') !== FALSE) {
        if($div->getAttribute('title') == 'news alert') {
            echo 'title found';
        }
        else {
            echo 'title not found';
        }
    }
}
```

Or perhaps [Query Path](http://api.querypath.org/docs/) which is tries to emulate jQuery server side:

```
$text = file_get_contents('http://example.com/path/to/file.html');
if(qp($text)->find('div.news[title="news alert"]')->is('*')) {
    echo('title found');
}
else {
    echo('title found');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DOMXPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to find it:

```
$dcmnt = new DOMDocument(); $dcmnt->loadHTML( $cntnt );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dcmnt );
$match = $xpath->query("//div[@title='news alert']");

echo $match->length ? "Found" : "Not Found" ;
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/CLdE8XCQ

Comment: I wrote a little CMS that constructed XMLs from the database schema, and used XSLT for templating. XPath queries in XSLT ar treated as objects. So using them as strings is wrong, you have to cast them to string first. That rookie mistake cost me a few hours. Hence an ingrained fobia of DOMXpath.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty simple:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://site.com/page.html');
if (strpos($html,'title="news alert"')!==false)
 echo 'title found';
```

Comment: strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )

Comment: no need to downvote, just fix the error next time instead to make a duplicated answers

Comment: @yes123 StackOverflow doesn't allow you to change your vote until an edit has been made to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
if(strpos($page, "title=\"news alert\"")!==false){
    echo 'title found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/';
$page = file_get_contents($url);

if(strpos($page, 'title="news alert"') !==false || strpos($page, 'title=\'news alert\'') !==false)
{
    echo 'website with news alert found';
}
else
{
    echo 'website not found';
}
```