# Is there a php script to search a website's source code

Tags: php, string, search, keyword

Basically I want a quick way to see if fifty sites have my javascript link. I need an engine or php script that can search source code of websites for my javascript link. The results I want it to be the url(s) that do have my script.

Comment: What have you tried?  cURL may be of use.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: This is exactly what I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758800/php-script-to-download-a-webpages-source-code-and-search-for-a-specific-string except I want to be adle to search adsense code so it needs to search for adsense code basically any indicator in the script

Comment: try http://nerdydata.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill in the array with your sites and put what you want searched in the `$adsensecode` variable.

```
<?php
   $adsensecode = "derpity derp";
   $arr = array("http://site1.com", "http://site2.com", "http://etc.com");
   foreach ($arr as $site) {
      $contents = file_get_contents($site);
      if ( strpos($contents, $adsensecode) !== false ) {
         echo "$site - adsense code found.<br />";
      }
   }
   unset($site); 
?>
```

Comment: instead of an array, how can you add the sites with a text field and it output the urls with the adsense code?

Comment: Use the <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php">`explode`</a> function to create an array from the submitted text field... for instance, `$arr = explode("|", $formfield);` (assuming you use "|" as the delimiter)